# How to turn off ultra power saving mode that was enabled for Huawei Android while it was on low power?

Tags: battery, huawei, power-options

My Huawei Android was on low power and it proposed to turn on ultra power saving mode. I accepted it. Now I have connected the phone to the charger but I can not enable other power modes. I am going to `"Settings - Device - Power Saving"` and there 3 modes are presented to me: 1) Ultra; 2) Smart; 3) Normal. The Ultra mode is enabled and I can not enable the other modes. When I try to enable other modes, the message appears and nothing happens:

```
This function can not be used in ultra power saving mode
```

So - is there way back to the normal power saving mode? I tried to Google this and some suggest to reset the phone to the factory settings. It is something incredible. There should be simple way out of this!? Why the ultra power saving mode is so protected?

Answer (score 0):

Simple restart of the phone automatically brought me back to the normal power saving mode. It was that simple. That is why, possibly, no further explanation is given on the net about turn of the ultra power saving mode.